# Laravel 5 Custom Classes Not Found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel 5.0 project. I added few customer classes in app\Libraries folder under namespace App\Libraries. Everything is working fine on localhost but when I deploy the project live it says my custom class not found. Gone through all the relevant threads but could not find any solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: try `composer update`

Comment: Thanks! It worked ver well.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `composer dump-autoload` on your server.